# Powerpoint crashes during VBA automation

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have an Excel macro that takes an existing Powerpoint template with chart objects and edits the data for each chart with data from an Excel worksheet.  The codes iterates thru 'n' number of rows in worksheet to create a series of 4 slides for each Excel row.

Oddly, for certain rows, one or more slides in the set produces an "Excel has stopped working" error, but the data seems to be installed correctly.  However, the problem point is an intermittent and somewhat random "Powerpoint has stopped working" error.  The powerpoint error crashes powerpoint entirely.  Both seem to occur as I get to around the 50 slide mark or so.

Here is the code for the 4th one in the set as an example.  The others are pretty much identical:

```
oPPT.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide Index:=5 + (4 * dIndex)

' SET OBJECT & CHART REFERENCES
Set shapeObject = oPPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(5 + (4 * dIndex)).Shapes("Chart 4")
Set myChart = shapeObject.Chart
Set gChartData = myChart.ChartData
Set gWorkbook = gChartData.Workbook
Set gWorksheet = gWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

' SET VALUES 
gWorksheet.Range("B2").Value = myWs.Range("Y" & dRow).Value
gWorksheet.Range("B3").Value = myWs.Range("AA" & dRow).Value
gWorksheet.Range("B4").Value = myWs.Range("Z" & dRow).Value
gWorksheet.Range("B5").Value = myWs.Range("X" & dRow).Value

Set shapeObject = Nothing
Set myChart = Nothing
Set gChartData = Nothing
Set gWorksheet = Nothing
gWorkbook.Close
Set gWorkbook = Nothing
```

The errors are completely random and occur during different iterations each time.  I have found that the 1st time I run never produces the PPT stopped working error.  Subsequent ones may.

Any ideas? I am baffled by what is happening here.

Note that I duplicate the template set into as many sets as I need before I iterate the Excel workbook.  E.g, if the Excel worksheet has 10 rows, I duplicate the 4 template slides 10 times before doing any edits to the underyling data.

Is there a timing issue going on perhaps?

Comment: just use www.pptxbuilder.com, it does the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing which seems to be missing is the activation call before accessing the embedded worksheet:

```
gChartData.Activate
```

This might explain the crashing issues.
cf. https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/chartdata-activate-method-powerpoint

Cheers
Jens